# Why is ajax 'GET' request hanging on an iOS phonegap app?

Tags: javascript, ios, ajax, cordova, xmlhttprequest

My phonegap app includes a javascript workflow to populate a web database (sqlite). The workflow consists of a sequence of ajax 'GET' requests that executed synchronously (the the individual ajax requests are async, but one request won't start until the previous one is finished).

I am observing that intermittently a request will hang (neither succeed nor fail) indefinitely. When I set a timeout on the ajax request, the request will timeout. When it does, the `XmlHttpRequest` has the following state:

```
status: 0
readyState: 0
statusText: 'timeout'
```

What blows my mind is that if I set up a proxy and watch the net traffic through fiddler, I see the request made, **and the expected response returned by the server** well within the 60 second timeout.

**Update:** if I monitor the net traffic of my dev iPad via the [developer tools on safari](http://developer.apple.com/library/safari/#documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariWebContent/DebuggingSafarioniPhoneContent/DebuggingSafarioniPhoneContent.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006515), I observe that the request does not seem to get a response. So it seems like the response is either not making it, or being ignored by the device.

I have not been able to reproduce this error on an nexus 7 running android, or running in chrome on my workstation, which leads me to believe the issue is specific to iOS (version 6.1.3)

Here is a simplified example of the applicable code:

```
function syncWebDatabase() {
    var sqlScript;

    return retrieveEntity('users', sqlScript )
        .then(function () {
            return retrieveEntity('accounts', sqlScript );
        })
        .then(function () {
            return retrieveEntity('orders', sqlScript );
        })
        .then(function () {
            return retrieveEntity('shipments', sqlScript );
        })
        .then(function () {
            return executeScript(sqlScript);
        });
}

function retrieveEntity(entityName, sqlScript) {
    return $.ajax({
             url: 'http://myrestfulservice/' + entityName,
             type: 'GET',
             dataType: 'json',
             timeout: 60000,
             error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
               //handle error condition
             }
           }).then(function (entites) {
               return generateInsertStatements(entities, sqlScript);
           })

}

function generateInsertStatements(entities, sqlScript) {
    //appends insert statement for each entity to sqlscript
}

function executeScript(sqlScript) {
    //executes sql script against web database
}
```

I would appreciate an explanation to what I am observing, as well as a solution to my problem or comments as to how to further investigate the issue.

Comment: Possibly related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4401608/javascript-xmlhttprequest-randomly-stuck-at-ready-state-1?rq=1

Comment: Sounds silly but have you added the website to the whitelist ?

Comment: What is a length of ajax GET parameters? It should not exceed 8000 symbols.